# In Clojure, how do I make a nested map return a map with an inner map all set to 0?

Tags: clojure, maps, iteration

So basically how do I make a function given the input `{:A 1 :B 2 :C {:X 5 :Y 5 :Z 5} :D 1}` and the key :C
return `{:A 1 :B 2 :C {:X 0 :Y 0 :Z 0} :D 1}`? It's the same mapping but with the nested map all set to 0. Given that we know that the key :C has the nested values.

I'm very new to clojure and I'm struggling with loops and iterations so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so far, so we can improve from there.

Comment: Also "nested" as in the example (first level) or all nesting (so basically all, but the first level)?

Comment: @cfrick I mean given that we know that :C is the key with the "nesting" we should only set its values to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defn with-zero-vals-at-key
  [m k]
  (update m k (fn [m2] (zipmap (keys m2) (repeat 0)))))

(with-zero-vals-at-key {:A 1 :B 2 :C {:X 5 :Y 5 :Z 5} :D 1} :C)
;; => {:A 1, :B 2, :C {:X 0, :Y 0, :Z 0}, :D 1}

;; OR

(defn with-zero-vals
  [m]
  (zipmap (keys m) (repeat 0)))

(update {:A 1 :B 2 :C {:X 5 :Y 5 :Z 5} :D 1}
        :C
        with-zero-vals)
;; => {:A 1, :B 2, :C {:X 0, :Y 0, :Z 0}, :D 1}
```